# QX30 and Sony API not working (was working correctly with QX100)

Tags: sony-camera-api

I have recently bought a QX30, but i'm having some issues. I have a working C# application that works well with a QX100 (using Kazyx) but i have some big issues with the QX30, for example:

- GetEventAsync doesn't work. Returns null, so i can't even poll for the camera status.
- GetAvailableStillSizeAsync() works, however when i try to set i.e. 18M using SetStillImageSizeAsync(), it just won't work and keep working at 2M.

I remember having a great pain with QX100s before realizing i had to update the firmware. Sadly, i can't seem to find any new firmware for QX30.

The application works perfectly on the QX100, however i had to chop and skip some features to have a "working" version that works on the QX30 as well. Am i missing something?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to insert a memory card in the camera. QX100 never complained, but QX30 will fail most API calls if no memory card is present. Odd.